# Problem understanding " must"

Tags: american-english

From the book : English Grammar and Exercises by L. R. H. Chapman, book 4:

"must is a defective verb, with only this one part, which is used to speak about the present time or a near future, as in these sentences: I must answer this letter at once; I must get up early tomorrow."

But then it is used in the both following examples with the past tense.

I really don't understand. Could you explain, please?

"After dinner Mr. Drew told the girls that he must leave 
the hotel for a few hours."
(The Haunted Bridge by Carolyn Keene)

"The chimes of a clock warned Nancy that she must return 
to the car to meet her father. "

(The Message in the Hollow Oak by Carolyn Keene)

Comment: The  thread you refer to doesn' really clarify  the issue I have. In that post, It was explained that "must" express the past in reported speech. But in the second example I provided there is no reported speech, at least in my understanding.

Comment: There is no reason why *must* can't refer to something in the past. *He didn't show up on time. He* ***must*** *have been delayed.* Here, it means "can only have been." Are you certain that the quotation from that grammar book isn't only talking about a specific use of the word? (However, in your second example, *must* is being used *relative to* the established past event of the clocks chiming. From her perspective *at that time*, it's referring to a present event.)

Comment: _Must_ is a [modal auxiliary verb](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299+modal+auxiliary+verbs). All modals are defective verbs, in that they only have one form -- no past, no infinitive, no gerund, no past participle -- so they don't refer to time at all. Just obligation/necessity in the case of _will, would, shall, should,_ and _must_,  or permission/possibility in the case of _can, could, may,_ and _might_. Forget about tenses with modals; they don't have any, not even present tense (*_He musts go now_).